# Something more effective than Sprite/BufferedImage.

Tags: java, process, processing, render, chunks

**Background information**

In school we learned 2 languages, Java and Processing
I know that Java and Processing arent the best languages for programming games.
It doesnt cared me ^^ so i started to work on a simple pacman ...

**Question 1**

Is there something more effective than Sprites/BufferedImages ?

**Question 2**

For rendering and drawing huge maps, is there a method to do that ? 
Normally it would lag when drawing it cause of all the images :)
But how i can render/draw large maps without any fps collapse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [Don't bother optimizing before you have a problem.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Longer answer: The most efficient way to do this is by using a game development framework, which handles this kind of thing for you. But really, stick with what you're comfortable with until you actually have a reason to change.

Java and Processing are **fine** languages for game development. There was a game called [Recluse](http://ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-23/?action=preview&uid=11981) a few years ago that did very well at [Ludum Dare](http://ludumdare.com/compo/) (a game programming competition), and it was done in Processing.

On the Java side, there are a ton of very popular game development frameworks. [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) is probably the most popular. In fact, the [libGDX Jam](http://itch.io/jam/libgdxjam) just happened, and you can check that out for a bunch of examples of what's possible in Java game development. You might also want to check out [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) and [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/).

I would say this: program with whatever you're comfortable with. If you're comfortable with Processing and Java and using sprites and BufferedImages, then do that. Don't worry about efficiency until you actually have a problem.

Processing is a great language to make some simple games. Start with Pong and Space Invaders. When you're ready to "graduate" to more complicated games, then check out libGDX. Don't worry about making everything as efficient as possible- focus on finishing games, which is much harder.

You'll also find a very active community of Java game developers on [JGO](http://www.java-gaming.org/).

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for your help mate :) i just tested recluse ... there are some processing examples in it ^^

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something more effective than Sprites/BufferedImages ?

No, not at your level of programming experience.

> For rendering and drawing huge maps, is there a method to do that ?

Tiles.  Generally tiles are 256 x 256 pixel images of one section of the map.  Like floor tiles, you place tiles together until you have a large enough graphic for your view.  As the player moves, you add the tiles in the direction the player is moving and remove the tiles from where the player came.

Here's an [introduction to creating a tile map engine](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-creating-a-tile-map-engine--gamedev-10900).

Comment: Thx you too :) yours was also helpfull